# Выполнение POST запроса

Tags: java, post

Есть код, который выполняет POST запрос по указанной ссылке. Код полностью рабочий.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL api = new URL("http://site.com/script.php");

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    parameters.put("parameter1", "value1");
    parameters.put("parameter2", "value2");
    parameters.put("parameter3", "value3");

    String query = parameters.keySet()
            .stream()
            .map(parameterName -> parameterName + '=' + parameters.get(parameterName))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) api.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.writeBytes(query);
    output.close(); //пробовал flush - ничего не отправляет.

    connection.getInputStream();
}
```

Меня смущает то, что если я не вызову `connection.getInputStream();`, то запрос не будет выполнен. Я считаю, что это не нормально. Как это делать правильно?